# Передать переменную в докер контейнер и использовать эту переменную в nginx.conf

Tags: nginx, docker

Пытаюсь передать переменную в docker контейнер и использовать эту переменную в nginx.conf в upstream.

Передаю переменную так:

```
docker run -e NIP="10.0.0.1" -p 80:80 -v /home/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf -d nginx
```

Получаю ошибку :

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown "nip" variable
```

nginx.conf выглядит так:

```
worker_processes auto;
env NIP;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    
    upstream site {
        server $NIP;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
       

        location / {
            
            proxy_pass http://$site;
        }
    }
}
```

При этом, если я убираю NIP из nginx.conf, то переменная таки записывается в окружение. Очень похоже, что nginx стартует раньше чем переменная записывается в окружение.
Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Переменные окружения не становятся переменными nginx. Проще заранее сгенерить правильный конфиг, перед запуском контейнера

Comment: Дело в том, что когда я беру существующие переменные из списка env, то они работают в nginx конфиге без проблем.

Comment: А, и вроде как в upstream нельзя использовать переменные

Comment: Получается что да - нельзя использовать переменные окружения в nginx. Это я просто случано выбрал переменную которая называется одинаково на системе и в nginx, и подумал что заюзал переменную из окружения.

Answer (score 1):

В официальном образе Nginx встроена утилита envsubstr, которая в процессе билда в шаблонах конфига умеет подставлять значения env переменных.
Для этого необходимо примонтировать папку с шаблонами в контейнер nginx в точку монтирования `/etc/nginx/templates`. Имена файлов шаблонов должны быть сформированы из имени файла конфига + суффикс .template. Например conf.d/default.conf -> conf.d/default.conf.template.

ENV переменную можно использовать так ${SERVER_NAME}.

Подробности доступны по ссылке в [документации](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) ищите подзаголовок **"Using environment variables in nginx configuration"**